# VBA code to Sort, Identify the last row and Clear contents

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a macro to do the following:

1. Sort by Column
2. Clear the contents of rows that do not contain "* Total" in Column C

The macro works if I hard code a range value for the last row of the spreadsheet, but since this row may change I want the macro to identify the last row and work back from there.

```
Sub SortandDelete()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    CC = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    Columns("A:AW").Sort key1:=Range("C1" & CC), _
       order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

    For MY_ROWS = Range("CC").End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
        If Range("C" & MY_ROWS).Value <> "*   Total:" Then
            Rows(MY_ROWS).ClearContents
        End If
    Next MY_ROWS

 End Sub
```

Comment: Please provide more details, what isnt working, what is the expected behaviour.  Where do you think your problem is?

Answer (score 2):

Please compare this to your code to see the coding errors:

```
Sub SortandDelete()
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim row As Long
    Dim r As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False

    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).row
    Columns("A:AW").Sort key1:=Range("C1:C" & lastrow), _
       order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

    For row = lastrow To 1 Step -1
        Set r = Range("C" & row)
        If r.Value <> "*   Total:" Then
            r.EntireRow.ClearContents
        End If
    Next row
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

You could make life easier for you if you'd use meaningful names for variables, and define them before use. Here, `CC` was a row number but later in the code you used it as a string (denoting a column "CC"). Then, you combined `CC` with a "C1" which certainly denotes a different row number than intended.
As you are only clearing the rows and not deleting them you could scan the range from top to bottom as well - the row number never changes by clearing the contents. But later you might be tempted to delete the rows entirely and then you'd need to do that from bottom up.